# How to invoke direct methods in Azure IoT Edge modules from the same device?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

In Azure IoT Edge modules, I can program direct methods to be invoked from the Azure Portal or from other resources within the Azure cloud. However, I am trying to call this direct methods directly from the edge device without the need to authenticate to Azure in any way (Because I am already in the device). Can this be done somehow?

Comment: Could you share more details with error screenshots

Comment: @Aswin There is no error. I am asking how to invoke the direct method, from within the device, but not necessarily from another IoT module.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, Direct Methods are one of the ways you have to communicate from the cloud (back-end services) to your devices (C2D communication): https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-c2d-guidance

You can invoke direct methods by leveraging the message broker. If both modules are connected to the edgeHub and there is a route to connect both, you can send a message from Module A to invoke a direct method in Module B. See: [How to call direct method on iot edge agent from another module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806134/how-to-call-direct-method-on-iot-edge-agent-from-another-module), there is a clear reference in the comments of the last answer.

Comment: Does this exposes an HTTP endpoint in the device to which I can directly send a request?

Comment: No, @sebsmgzz, you'll have to build that part yourself.

Comment: Correct @sebsmgzz, I you want, you can expose an HTTP(S) endpoint in in your module (container) as a facade of your Direct Method, then you can invoke directly.